# How to specify variable bounds in a clean way?

Tags: frama-c

```
/*@
    requires 0 <= lb < N_LOG_BLOCKS &&  0 <= lp < N_PAGE ;
    requires  (  1 <= h_clean_counter + l_clean_counter <= N_PHY_BLOCKS );
    requires 0 <= h_act_block_index_p < N_PHY_BLOCKS &&   0 <= h_act_page_p < N_PAGE;
    requires 0 <= l_act_block_index_p < N_PHY_BLOCKS &&   0 <= l_act_page_p < N_PAGE;
    requires 0 <= l_to_p[lb][lp] < N_PHY_BLOCKS * N_PAGE || l_to_p[lb][lp] == -1;
    requires -2147483648 <= d <= 2147283647 ;
    requires 0 <=  chance_index_p < LRU_SIZE;
    requires 0 <= index_2_physical[h_act_block_index_p] < N_PHY_BLOCKS ;
    requires \forall integer i; 0 <= i < N_PHY_BLOCKS ==> 0 <= index_2_physical[i] < N_PHY_BLOCKS;

    requires 0 <= l_array_counter < N_PHY_BLOCKS/2;
    requires l_clean_counter == low_array_counter;
    requires h_clean_counter == high_array_counter;
...
*/
```

My code has tons of variables with some intended bound. As a result, I need to put all these bound constraints in all "requires" and "ensures" regions of all functions.  I wonder whether there is a smarter way for me to specify the variable bound, preferably in a global manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these bounds are indeed the same for all functions and you have global variables or the formals are consistently named across all functions, I'd say that this is something [MetAcsl](https://frama-c.com/fc-plugins/metacsl.html) can do for you, with something like (for your first `requires`)

```
/*@ meta \prop,
  \name(lb_bounds),
  \context(\precond),
  \targets(\ALL),
  0 <= lb < N_LOG_BLOCKS;
*/
```

[NB: I haven't tried to type-check it, it may contain typos]

Basically, this tells MetAcsl to insert a pre-condition (because of the `\precond` context) to `\ALL` functions saying `0<= lb < N_LOG_BLOCKS`.
You can find more information about the annotations that can be generated by MetAcsl on its [gitlab repository](https://git.frama-c.com/pub/meta).